Server certificate has expired
When I try to log in to my mail client I get this:
This certificate belongs to:
   mail.ssk.pm

This certificate was issued by:
   R3
   Let's Encrypt
   US

This certificate is valid
   from Thu, 21 Mar 2024 18:03:06 UTC
     to Wed, 19 Jun 2024 18:03:05 UTC

SHA1 Fingerprint: 2BAC DF4D 2E6A BC4B BDBB 9746 6A39 D523 9306 DE4A
SHA256 Fingerprint: 2BAC DF4D 2E6A BC4B BDBB 9746 6A39 D523
                    9306 DE4A87A9 CAC5 AAD1 6E8A 8796 9232 D4B6 4EAB 97EF ECEF 437D 1BFC 4369 96AE 6FF4 C503

WARNING: Server certificate has expired

But when I do certbox --nginx renew I get this:
certbot --nginx renew
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mail.ssk.pm.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Certificate not yet due for renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/ssk.pm.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Certificate not yet due for renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
The following certificates are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ssk.pm/fullchain.pem expires on 2024-08-19 (skipped)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/ssk.pm/fullchain.pem expires on 2024-08-18 (skipped)
No renewals were attempted.

Am I missing something here?

Make sure that service really uses the path /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ssk.pm/fullchain.pem. Reload or restart the service for it to forcibly load the updated certificate (and add the reload into the certificate renew hook). Overall, this question was asked far too many times on ServerFault, why don't you bother to use search?

It would have been helpful if you had said what your MUA was or given SOME CLUE as to whether the expired certificate relates to HTTPS access to the MUA or the MUAs access to SMTP/IMAP.

exactly which service are you referring to? postfix?

This happens when the renewed certificate is not properly deployed or when the mail server is not correctly configured to use the updated certificate.
Verify the certificate paths:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ssk.pm/fullchain.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ssk.pm/privkey.pem

Manually check the certificate expiry:
openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ssk.pm/fullchain.pem -noout -dates

Then restart the services that use the certificate. If something still doesn't work, then it should be in the logs.
Certbot maintains its own log files, which are usually located in the /var/log/letsencrypt/ directory. You can check these logs to see the output of the certbot renew command.
cat /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

If there are any issues with running the cron job itself, such as syntax errors or permission issues, these will typically be logged in the system's cron logs. On many systems, cron logs can be found in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/cron.log.
grep CRON /var/log/syslog

or
cat /var/log/cron.log

By default, cron sends the output of the jobs it runs (including any errors) to the local email of the user who scheduled the cron job. You can check this by reading the local mail for the user:
mail 

Good luck!

This happens when... this is a great (and probably accurate) answer. I would add that "this happens" also because most organizations just aren't checking certificates and haven't incorporated into their maintenance regimes.

What kind of person deploys Letsencrypt certificates without at least automating updates? (monitoring is a little more esoteric but still needed).

I might add that even though certbot has renewed the certificate it does not necessarily reload the MUA as part of the renewing. I use acme.sh instead which trigger both a pre- and post hook that amongst others restarts web, smtp and imap server ... and whatever else that is using the Let's Encrypt certificate. I do not know if certbot can do something similar.

Which services exactly do I need to reload here? Postfix and dovecot?

If it's down, it won't hurt to restart both, that way you get a chance to look at the initialization logs... I would.
sudo systemctl restart postfix
sudo systemctl restart dovecot
And totally agree with our mates who've mentioned in the comments, that you should automate the certificate renewal.

Is it enough to add 0 0 1 * * certbot --nginx renew to crontab -e for the certificates to renew automatically?

Sure, but that'd only run once/month, giving you fewer retry opportunities if something goes wrong; Let's Encrypt certificates are valid for 90 days, and it is generally recommended to renew them every 60 days to avoid any potential downtime.
A more appropriate approach is to schedule the cron job to run twice a day. This ensures that if there are any issues during one attempt, there will be multiple opportunities to successfully renew the certificate before it expires:
0 0,12 * * * certbot renew --nginx --quiet

Thank you guys for your help!

Where do I find the logs for this matter so I can check if the cron works properly?

I have updated my answer with log explanations and locations where one may find them.

Thank you a lot for your help!
